# Explicit description of dualizing sheaf of nodal curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, serre-duality

Let $C$ be a nodal curve with one single node $p$ and $f: N \to C$ it's normalization. Let $r,s $ preimages of $p$. In [Geometry of Algebraic Curves](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-69392-5) (p 91) is stated without proof that the dualizing sheaf $\omega_C$ can be explicitly described as invertible subsheaf $\omega_C \subset f_*(\Omega_N(r+s))$ with sections $\varphi \in \omega_C (C)$ beeing sections of $\Omega_N(r+s)$ of satisfying the condition

$$ \text{Res}_r(\varphi) +\text{Res}_s(\varphi)=0  $$

where $\text{Res}_x:\Omega_{\text{Frac}(C)} \to \kappa(x)$ is the residue map (details eg in [Hartshorne](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-3849-0), p 248).

I'm seeking for a source discussion in detail why this gives exactly the dualizing sheaf of the nodal curve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually a proof in Geometry of Algebraic Curves - a bit after formula 2.19. However this description is indirect and in particular doesn't use the normalization map. Here's a less elementary proof that does use it:

Let $X$ be a nodal curve, say with a single node $q$. Let $\nu :\tilde{X} \to X$ be its normalization with $\nu^{-1}(p)=\{p_1,p_2\}$. Let $\imath : \{q\} \hookrightarrow X$ and $\jmath : X \backslash q \hookrightarrow X$. Similarly $\tilde{\imath} : \{p_1,p_2\} \hookrightarrow \tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{\jmath} : \tilde{X} \backslash \{p_1,p_2\} \hookrightarrow \tilde{X}$. We get an exact triangle

$$\tilde{\imath}_*\tilde{\imath}^!\omega_{\tilde{X}} \to \omega_{\tilde{X}} \to \tilde{\jmath}_*\tilde{\jmath}^!\omega_{\tilde{X}}$$ or
$$\tilde{\imath}_*\omega_{\{p_1,p_2\}} \to \omega_{\tilde{X}} \to \tilde{\jmath}_*\omega_{\tilde{X} \backslash \{p_1,p_2\}}$$
and similarly for $X$. $\nu$ induces a map between the sequences, which is an isomorphism on the last term and a sum for the first one. This, together with the fact that the first term is concentrated in degree $0$ and the last two in degree $1$ implies that $\omega_X$ is the kernel of $\nu_* \tilde{\jmath}_*\omega_{\tilde{X} \backslash \{p_1,p_2\}} \xrightarrow{\text{res}} \nu_*\tilde{\imath}_*\omega_{\{p_1,p_2\}}[1] \xrightarrow{\text{sum}}\imath_*\omega_{q}[1]$
i.e. exactly elements of $\omega_{\tilde{X}}(\infty\{p_1,p_2\})$ with residue summing to zero and any higher order poles vanishing.